# SQL Efficiency Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to know the most efficient way to perform the below query. I have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
    Table1Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
go

CREATE TABLE Table2 (
    Table2Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    EndDate DATE NULL,
    Table1Id INT NOT NULL
);
go
```

I would like to know all of the Table1IDs that are not in Table 2 or if they are in table 2 they must have an EndDate before the current date.

I know I can do a right join but not sure how to tackle the EndDate piece. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It would add great value to your question if you would provide some sample data from the 3 tables and an expected result.

Comment: Table 1 Records: 1; 2; 3; 4; 5;          Table 2 Records: 1,11012015,1; 2,12112015,2; 3,, 1;  4, 12312015, 4;                  The query should return the following Table 1 ID's: 2, 3, 5.                I hope this helps. Thank you.

Comment: You should remember that the most efficient TSQL query will be not efficient if you will have no index, partitioning, compression etc Of course it's depend on the table size, but do not forgive about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work fairly well:

```
Select distinct Table1Id from Table1 left join Table2 using (Table1Id)
where Table2Id is null or EndDate < now();
```

Maybe you need to replace `using (Table1Id)` by `on (Table1.Table1Id = Table2.Table1Id)` on MSSQL.

Comment: sql server doesnt use now,maybe the OP has misplaced tags

Answer (score 0):

I would look at it in two parts. First, get all the records from `Table1` that are not in table 2. This is done with a left join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM dbo.Table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Table2 t2
        ON t1.Table1Id = t2.Table1Id
WHERE t2.Table2Id IS NULL
```

For the next part, you want the records from `Table1` that do have a match in `Table2`, but the `EndDate` before the current date. The `LEFT JOIN` already will return the records from `Table1` that have a match in `Table2`, we just have to modify the `WHERE` clause to check the `EndDate` if `t2.Table2Id` is not null. That would give the final query of:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM dbo.Table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Table2 t2
        ON t1.Table1Id = t2.Table1Id
WHERE t2.Table2Id IS NULL
    OR t2.EndDate < CONVERT(date, GETDATE());
```

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't sure if I needed to make 2 calls or if I could accomplish it in 1 query. I thought about using a union but was not sure on best practice.